# PHP редирект для Яндекс.Метрика

Tags: php, google-adwords

Имеется сайт для которого запущена рекламная компания от Google Adwords. Так же на сайте стоит система сбора статистики Яндекс Метрика. Для сбора статистических данных о кол-ве переходов по рекламе было принято решение использовать UTM метки, а именно utm_sourse.

**Целевая страница:**

http://bestlikes.ru/

**URL с UTM меткой:**

http://bestlikes.ru/?utm_source=google

При добавлении меток Adwords сказал о том что должен быть в итоге редирект на целевую страницу. Я реализовал редирект на PHP на целевую со страницы с меткой. В PHP функцию header() можно использовать только до вывода HTML/JS и т.д. контента, а сам счетчик Yandex в эту категорию входит. Получается редирект произойдет сразу и счетчик засчитать переход по рекламе не успеет, прошу подсказать реализацию сбора статистики с помощью UTM меток. Спасибо!

Comment: В коде php проверяйте наличие реферера и его содержимое до начала вывода страницы. И дальше делайте, что вздумается.

Comment: А как я могу реферера передать JS коду метрики? Насколько я понимаю метрика собирает данные по текущему URL

Comment: Редирект в php сделайте на url с нужной меток utm_source. Хотя, возможно, лучше это в .htaccess сделать или в конфигурации nginx, смотря что используете.

Comment: Редирект релизован уже. Вот код:
if(isset($_GET['utm_source'])) {
 header('Location: http://www.bestlikes.ru/');
 exit;
}
Адвордсу все нравится, а вот яндекс метрика не видит переходы т.к. js код его не успевает подгружаться

Comment: У вас какой редирект реализован? Метку убираете что ли, что яндекс ее не видит?

Comment: Да, приходится убирать ибо адвордс этого требует, т.к. в итоге должен быть редирект на целевую страницу

Comment: Тогда на странице через php добавьте параметры визитов https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/data/visit-params.xml со своими данными.